# How do I make a link to a url using Markdown?

Tags: url, markdown

OK, here is a url that I tried linking to in an answer on [this](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Expanded_columns_in_folders_pane_(Thunderbird)) page:

`http://kb.mozillazine.org/Expanded_columns_in_folders_pane_(Thunderbird)`

If you click on the link, you will see that the link doesn't work as the closing bracket is omitted.

How am I supposed to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the solution is to put a '`\`' before the closing parenthesis.

So this:

> `http://kb.mozillazine.org/Expanded_columns_in_folders_pane_(Thunderbird)`

becomes this:

> `http://kb.mozillazine.org/Expanded_columns_in_folders_pane_(Thunderbird\ )` (without the extra space)

However, SuperUser seems to support URLs with the closing parenthesis in them, so it shouldn't be a problem here.

[Source](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/800qs/reddits_markdown_system_sucks_blindly_intepreting/c07vl89)

Comment: This does not work and I do not know why it was accepted as the answer, I even tested it.

Comment: +1. It works and the question of author never mentioned SuperUser in particular. In fact, if this was a SuperUser specific question, it would have to be moved to meta(http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: My mistake, I should have taken a bit more time to understand the question being asked.

Comment: No worries. Sorry I was a bit harsh in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

[http://kb.mozillazine.org/Expanded_columns_in_folders_pane_(Thunderbird)](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Expanded_columns_in_folders_pane_%28Thunderbird%29)

```
[1]: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Expanded_columns_in_folders_pane_%28Thunderbird%29
```

Use URL Encoding opening bracket ( = %28 and closing bracket ) = %29

Source: [URL Encoded Characters](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php)